# "Manage Articles" permission not visible in profile settings

Tags: knowledge, lightning-knowledge

I am trying to locate user permissions defined in this salesforce article.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_setup_users_lex.htm&type=5

I am not able to locate any of them under **System Permissions** section in any profile.

Salesforce edition : Performance and we have knowledge base license.

Where can I find these permissions ?

Comment: try this https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000glFNAAY

Comment: @AbhishekMudireddy thanks for lead. That discuss about Knowledge in Salesforce Classic and I looking for lightning Knowledge permission setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the Manage Article permission under "App Permissions" of profile.Once you go to the App permissions then you will be see this permission under "Knowledge Management" sub category.

Adding the screenshot for the reference.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Shirisha It helped